# Why doesn't the compiler complain in the definition of the Derived class constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Notice that the `Derived` class constructor has `ii` as its first argument, but the argument passed to `Base` was made equal to `i` on purpose.

```
class Base
{
    protected:
    int i;

    public:
    Base(int i) : i(i) {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    private:
    int k;

    public:
    Derived(int ii, int k) : Base(i), k(k) {}  // Why not C2065: 'i' undeclared identifier
};

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Surely the compiler has enough information here to know the code is using an unitialised variable. It doesn't complain because the development team decided to use their precious man-hours to develop other things instead of this (like some C++11 support in VS2010).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `i` is a member variable inherited from `Base`, so it **is** defined. You can freely access member variables in initialiser lists, but what you're doing is accessing a variable before it's initialised, which is, I believe, Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Could you give an example where this would be valid ?

Comment: @jaayrosa where what would be valid? Initialising a base member? In that case, if `Base` didn't have a constructor to initialise `i`, you'd want to initialise it yourself by doing `Derived(int ii, int k) : i(ii), k(k) {}`. Passing an uninitialised variable as an argument is never valid, however.

Comment: Your example is pretty clear to me. What I don't understand is why the compiler doesn't emit C2065, since the variable passed to `Base` is different from the one passed to `Derived`.

Comment: @jaayrosa C2065 is `undeclared identifier`. However, `i` is completely, utterly and perfectly declared, so it's not undeclared, so it wouldn't emit C2065. The compiler doesn't care how you use arguments, or even that you use them at all.

Comment: So what you're saying is that this definition of the `Derived` ctor would be valid and it would work all right : `Derived(int ii, int k) : Base(ii), k(i) {}`

Comment: @jaayrosa yeah since `Base(ii)` initialises `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Because it sees `i` from base class and uses it in initializer. If you change protected to private, you will get an error about `Base::i` being private.